# PHP regular expression to delete all after last alphanumeric character

Tags: php, regex

I have a whole load of data generated from a hefty mysql query, returning a load of values that are essentially comma separated lists.  The lists contain up to 30 values.  However all contain 30 commas, leading to this sort of thing:

```
x, xx, xxx, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 
x, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 
x, xx, xxx, xxxx, xxxxx, xxxxxx, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
```

Eventually I'd like to tidy up the query to remove these excess separators, but that's going to be a long term job due the complexity of the query.  For now, I think best bet to remove them is using a regular express to match the last alphanumeric character (99% of the time it'll be a letter, but there MIGHT be occurences of numerals), and then remove everything after it.

Does that make sense?  If so, I've no idea where to start - any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: what is your desired output you want from this:-

Comment: `$str = rtrim($str, ' ,');` perhaps.

Comment: what is your list, is it an array of strings?

Comment: I don't know how your mysql query looks like. but I think removing the commas at the database level would be better approach

Comment: From the above example I'd simply like:
    x, xx, xxx
    x
    x, xx, xxx, xxxx, xxxxx, xxxxxx

Data is currently returned in an array.  I thought about the rtrim approach, but I think it'll remove all the genuine ", " occurrences too.

Comment: rtrim() did work - for some reason I thought it would replace all occurrences of the offending string from the main string...of course when I actually stopped to think about it...!

Many thanks all!